# Toxic Metals and Oxidative Phosphorylation

Tags: biochemistry, molecular-biology, toxicology

I was reviewing the toxicity of certain toxic metals, specifically cadmium and their effect on Oxidative Phosphorylation and Cellular Respiration, I have found that metals such as cadmium inhibit certain antioxidant enzymes such as catalase, resulting in oxidative stress as a result of excess of Reactive Oxygen Species or free radicals, I also have come across information that states that toxic metals can bind to the mitochondria and interfere with oxidative phosphorylation, possibly in the electron transfer change or in another way. I was wondering if anyone is aware of the other ways in which cadmium interferes with oxidative phosphorylation as it bonds with the mitochondria, or if attaching to antioxidant enzymes IS actually binding to the mitochondria.